# UIActivityIndicator Not Spinning With GCD

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm making a very simple app to practice multi-threading using GCD. I initialized a UIActivityIndicatorView in my ViewController class like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myActivityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
```

In my viewDidLoad, I added it as a subView to my main view with the following code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myActivityIndicator.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)
}
```

Then when my button is tapped, I have an IBAction that handles the event by printing a simple message after a little while. Here is the code for that:

```
@IBAction func doSomething(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0))
    {
        self.myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

        sleep(3)

        print("This has been accessed on another thread")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

It seems as though self.myActivityIndicator.startAnimating() isn't getting called, but when I put that line of code in viewDidLoad, it works just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: just call myActivityIndicator.startAnimating() from the main queue

Comment: @LeoDabus Wow that did the trick. I can't believe I overlooked that...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by starting the animation on the main thread:

```
 @IBAction func doSomething(sender: AnyObject)
{
    self.myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the main thread can update UI. So you must put the update UI's action in main thread. Add **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { updateSomeUI(); }**

But when in load view controller in viewDidLoad(), it just happened in the main thread, and it can immediately update the UI.
[When code executed in viewDidLoad()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3mdw.png)
[When code executed in buttonClick()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp8oU.png)

```
@IBAction func doSomething(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0))
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
        {
            self.myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        }

        sleep(3)

        print("This has been accessed on another thread")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

-Good Luck.